# Use CSS to create table of contents (image and block of text, aligned)

Tags: css, image, text, alignment, css-tables

I'm trying to create a sort-of table of clips on my webpage. The idea is that it's basically (in my mind) a table with a thumbnail in the left column, and then a right column would house a title, where the story appeared, a date, and a description. I have no trouble doing this using HTML `<table>` but I'm trying very hard to get better at CSS.

I've combed this (very helpful) site and am far ahead of where I was this morning. However, I'm having trouble with setting the "height." I don't want to set a firm height. I want the "row" to adjust to the height of an image or block of text, and for the height to be the same for both "columns."

Right now I have this.

HTML:

```
    <p class="imageclass">thumbnail</p>
    <p class="textclass">all sorts of text, separated by line breaks</p>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
 width:620px;
}

.imageclass {
     float:left;
     width:120px;
}

.textclass {
     float:left;
     width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have added a link. Here's the page-in-progress: http://speciesrichness.com/portfolio/

Comment: Using appropriate HTML to associate the thumbnails with the text would be a better choice; I'd *suggest* using a `ul` (or `ol`) with child elements if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying `overflow: hidden` to `.container`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is really going to be a "row", why not wrap all of the content in a div?  This div will scale to be the height of its tallest child.  Then if you need to manipulate the rows you can just use CSS selectors for the row class:

```
<div class="row">
    <p style="height:200px; background: black;" class="imageclass">thumbnail</p>
    <p class="textclass">all sorts of text, separated by line breaks</p>
</div>
```